# rosinstall file location in repository

Tags: rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a default location where to put rosinstall files, such as, `some_repo_minimal.rosinstall` and `some_repo_demos.rosinstall`, within a git repo containing some packages (including a meta package).
For now, they are placed it in the meta package, as shown below:

- `some_repo`

  - `some_repo` (meta_package)

    - `package.xml`
    - `CMakeLists.txt`
    - `some_repo_minimal.rosinstall`
    - `some_repo_demos.rosinstall`
  - `package_one`
  - `package_two`
  - ...
  - `.gitignore`
  - `README.md`

But I am not sure if this is a good location.
Would it be better to place it in the root folder, or is there no convention for this.

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205949/rosinstall-file-location-in-repository/) by [ffurrer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3149/ffurrer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just my two cents: as far as I know there is no real convention for this. I always place them in the root of the repository (so as a sibling, next to the packages).

I've also seen projects where the `.rosinstall` files (and all other installation related materials) were placed in a separate repository, but that does not seem to be too common.

Personally I wouldn't place `.rosinstall` files in a metapackage, but there is no technical reason for that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3149/ffurrer/) on 2015-03-26**:
ok, I had the same thoughts, thanks.